# Passing command line arguments in lein repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a main function declaration which accepts command line arguments

```
(defn -main [& args]
    (let [options (cli/parse-opts args [["-k", "--key KEY","Secret key"]
                                        ["-u", "--user USER", "User name"]])]
        (println user key)))
```

I am trying to load this in `lein repl` for debugging, but unable to figure out how to pass arguments over REPL.

I have tried multiple methods to pass the args over repl including

`(-main "key-val" "user-val")` (prints `nil nil`)

`(-main ("key-val" "user-val"))` (prints `nil nil`)

I tried multiple failing attempts as well trying to pass a list or vector which throw cast errors.

Comment: Does (or could) the cast error point to the type you should be passing in? Also can you just try printing `args` without the intervening step of them being parsed. Perhaps "key-val" "user-val" are being passed in fine.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy that was the issue. I should have printed args and checked. As per the accepted answer, the arguments were getting passed just fine, but weren't parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have defined params with keys "-k" and "-u", but haven't passed the keys to the function, so the parser won't be able to guess what do you expect it to get. The working version is like this:

```
user> (defn -main [& args]
        (let [options (cli/parse-opts args [["-k", "--key KEY","Secret key"]
                                            ["-u", "--user USER", "User name"]])
              {:keys [key user]} (:options options)]
          [key user]))
#'user/-main

user> (-main "-k" "key-val" "-u" "user-val")
;;=> ["key-val" "user-val"]

user> (-main "--key" "key-val" "--user" "user-val")
;;=> ["key-val" "user-val"]
```

Comment: Works perfect. The oversight seems too obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that `user` and `key` are not bound to result of `parse-opts`. 
[*parse-opts* returns a map](http://clojure.github.io/tools.cli/index.html#clojure.tools.cli/parse-opts) where these options are under the key `:options`. 
Let's bind the result as follows:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [options (parse-opts args [["-k", "--key KEY","Secret key"]
                                  ["-u", "--user USER", "User name"]])
        user (get-in options [:options :user])
        key  (get-in options [:options :key])]
    (println user key)))
```

Your *parse-opts* call specifies that you expect *named arguments*, i.e., *options* to parse. A call like the following works from REPL:

```
(-main "-k a" "-u b") ; prints "b a"
```

Note that if you specify positional arguments, they are under the key `:arguments`. After changing the example to print the value bound to options (`(println options)`), your example call would work like so:

```
(-main "key-val" "user-val") ; {:arguments [key-val user-val] :options {} ...}
```

So the call was made without *options*, that is, without specifying *named arguments*.